# Any nonempty open subsets of a variety have a nonempty intersection

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

I have seen that any nonempty open subsets of a variety $Z$ have a nonempty intersection but I am not sure why this is true. I guess the point is that a variety is irreducible and an empty intersection of open sets should give me a contradiction however I fail to see the contradiction. Say $U_1,U_2$ are open and disjoint in $Z$ then $Z-U_1$ and $Z-U_2$ are closed in $Z$ and $Z$=$(Z-U_1)\cup (Z-U_2)$. That would be a contradiction if those sets were closed. I mean we know that they are closed in $Z$ however we can't say that they are closed in the whole space $A^n$. So how do I prove the statement?

Answer (score 1):

This is just pure topology.  Suppose $X$ is a topological space, and we have $Z \subseteq Y \subseteq X$ with $Y$ a closed subset of $X$ and $Z$ a closed subset of $Y$.  I claim that $Z$ is a closed subset of $X$.

By definition of the subspace topology, then $Z = W \cap Y$ for some closed subset $W$ of $X$.  Then
$$
X \setminus Z = X \setminus (W \cap Y) = (X \setminus W) \cup (X \setminus Y)
$$
which is a union of open sets of $X$, hence is open in $X$.  Thus $Z$ is closed in $X$.

Back to your example: since $Z$ is a variety, it is closed in $\mathbb{A}^n$.  Your sets $Z \setminus U_i$ are closed in $Z$, hence closed in $\mathbb{A}^n$ by the above.

Comment: Just as an aside, are you sure your definition of irreducible requires that the sets be closed in the ambient affine space, and not just as subsets of the variety?  I ask because, while these are the same for an affine variety, they are not for a quasiprojective variety.